# WPF | Разный DataContext для разных элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В примере с использованием MVVM контекст данных вводили прямо в .xaml.cs файле, типа `DataContext = new ViewModel();`. Но если так сделать, то контекст из привязанного класса (VM) станет распространяться на весь xaml файл (т.е. View), но мне нужно, чтобы в интерфейсе для определенных элементов контекст данных был из разных ViewModel'ей. Например

```
// У этого элемента допустим в качестве контекста класс GameViewModel
<Grid>
   <TextBlock Text={Binding Title}/>
</Grid>

// А у этого элемента в качестве контекста класс AchievementViewModel
<Grid>
   <TextBlock Text={Binding Title}/>
</Grid>
```

Т.е. мне просто нужно брать контекст из разных классов, а не запихивать все в один VM, как это сделать?

Comment: 1) Прогписывать для каждого элемента свой контекст 2) Сделать мега-VM, собрать в ней все контексты и забиндить её на, например, всё окно, а внутри окна уже привязками распределять контексты как надо\

Comment: @tym32167 
1) Ну так ведь я и спрашиваю как это сделать
2) Как вариант, но это получится как костыль, особенно если кода много, то искать там все станет очень проблематично + названия свойств тоже придется изменять, чтобы не было повторений

Comment: 1) myUserControl.DataContext = new MyViewModel()

Comment: 2) Для этого и придумывают фреймворки всякие, или вам надо писать что то типа мини-фреймворка самому

Comment: например, я когда то писал менеджер представлений, чтобы  во вьюмодели можно было сделать вот так `viewManager.ShowViewFor<ViewModel>(parentViewId)`. Такие примеры есть где то тут на сайте, если поищите. Похожий функционал есть в том же PRISM, например.

Comment: @tym32167 а хотя все-таки с мега-VM не такая уж и плохая идея, благодарю

Comment: @FirstSin, так и делают. Называется MainVM)